# Nginx redirecting to (seemingly) random domain

Tags: nginx, redirect, php-fpm

My brain is breaking over this. Every site I have is redirecting back to one of my other ones... I would say it was the /default site, but it wasn't until I just made it the default site, which changed nothing. All urls put me back at www.justaleaf.com

(all websites worked prior to transition, and the myhashimotos site was working a little bit ago due to the redirect landing there when I disabled all the other sites)

Here are my configurations (ubuntu with mysql php-fpm)... I'm new to nginx and I'm just lost now:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        #tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        limit_req_zone  $binary_remote_addr  zone=one:10m   rate=1r/s;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }


    #mail {
    #       # See sample authentication script at:
    #       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
    #
    #       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
    #       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
    #       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
    #
    #       server {
    #               listen     localhost:110;
    #               protocol   pop3;
    #               proxy      on;
    #       }
    #
    #       server {
    #               listen     localhost:143;
    #               protocol   imap;
    #               proxy      on;
    #       }
    #}
```

directory contents

```
justaleaf@webserver  /etc/nginx/sites-available
$ ls -a
.   default           www.harmonicult.com  .www.justaleaf.com.swp
..  default.dpkg-old  www.justaleaf.com    www.myhashimotosthyroiditis.com
justaleaf@webserver  /etc/nginx/sites-available
$ ls -a ../sites-enabled
.   www.justaleaf.com   www.myhashimotosthyroiditis.com
..  www.harmonicult.com
```

And here are my site confs:

[/www.myhashimotosthyroiditis.com](http://pastie.org/3801845)

[/www.harmonicult.com](http://pastie.org/3801824)

[/www.justaleaf.com](http://pastie.org/3801818)

Note: to test, just try going to myhashimotosthyroiditis.com, the redirect is obvious there.

Comment: Why do you have a default.conf and a www.justaleaf.com conf with the same info in it?  Have you tried removing default.conf?

Comment: yeah, actually, those two aren't usually up at the same time. I was trying to use the default conf to see if nginx would listen to me if it were named that. I'm going to drop default, for now.

Answer (score 2):

The second server in harmonicult has a / in it; line 12 in http://pastie.org/3801824
Pretty sure that's not allowed in server_name.

(Tried to make this as a comment, but I need rep for that, so oh well. Hopefully this helps.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... unfortunately that didn't impact this situation.

Comment: Could you rehost the configs? pastie.org went down and I'd like to give this another try.